# How can my monitor be awoken after Windows 7 resumes?

Tags: windows-7, batch, sleep

I have a script that makes the computer sleep at 8pm and wake/resume at 8am. The scripts run perfectly fine, but when it wakes at 8am, the monitor doesn't turn on until the mouse is moved. How can I get the effect of the mouse moving (aka: turning on the monitor) with no human intervention?

Command line (cmd.exe) options preferred.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't think of any way to turn on the monitor with CMD strictly, you could invoke a [precompiled](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm)(for link see Convert a Script to an EXE (ahk2exe)) [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script with CMD easily which could move your mouse to wake it up.

Something like `MouseClick, left,  0, 0` should work

Comment: That'd be nice, but I can't install anything on this machine. Is there no pre-existing setting or cmd I can run?

Comment: Brett, you don't actually need to install anything, you can precompile it on another machine into an EXE file which can be launched directly without any need of AHK installation(I've updated my above comment for a precompile link). As for preexisiting settings. You could probably disable the screen blanking in power settings though I can't say I've tried this from sleep. As for in CMD, I don't think so, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can turn them on, but check out [wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm).
Also, there are several auto mouse move apps around.  Find one with cmd line access.

Comment: wizmo only has 'monoff' not 'monon'